Install snort error with make
make[2]: *** [scr/js_norm/CMakeFiles/js_norm.dir/build.make:106: 
src/js_norm/CMakeFiles/js_norm.dir/js_tokenizer.cc.o] Error 1

When I run the command make -j $(noproc) I get an error like on the code at the top, I work with the instructions according to this https://docs.snort.org/start/installation, I have installed all the required dependencies. I'm trying to install snort from the source but I always encounter a terminal freeze at the end and I have to restart the virtual machine in VirtualBox, and I'm trying to install snort on ubuntu server 23.10. The only thing that is new is the appearance of this error that I posted the code, so I can suggest that.

In what way is the snort package from Ubuntu universe not what you want?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/mantic/snort

If you have any questions related to programming, you can find help on Stack Overflow. In case you require more information, you may need to run with verbose. However, in most cases, it is unnecessary to build everything from scratch for the most common business practices in the current century.

Thanks for commenting, i will download all those packages from link and post on stack overflow, and run make with verbose mode.
